# Automatically webcam not working - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, drivers, hardware, bios, webcam

I checked my HP laptop bios setting but I didn't found any wecam related hardware there.
For Ubuntu 18.04 there is no webcam driver is available in HP. Help Me to get rid this problem.

1. How can I found hardware(Webcam enable or disable option) in BIOS HP ?
2. webcam driver in Ubuntu ?

Comment: Webcam is usually not in BIOS as there is nothing to be configured there for a webcam. How do you know, you do not have the driver for a webcam?

Comment: because from 3 months I continuously used wecam but two days before I updated it then this prob may or maynot be happened thats why I thinked that its a driver prob...

Comment: So the webcam worked before the recent update? Try this `restart computer --> advanced options for Ubuntu --> choose an old kernel`